# List<something> and GridView editing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to bind a List to a GridView and have the editing features work?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to an ObjectDataSource, but you will need to implement some methods on the backend and hook them up to your data source to handle the updates since the data source itself doesn't know anything about how to persist data.

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) that describes this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but this is how I did it, and it works better than any other answer I've found. I took all the best bits from other answers.
The method I've used allows you to edit one line, converting only the required editable fields to textboxes, and a dropdownlist for items that can be selected then the id saved for the item selected.

Database tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPerson] (
    [Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Surname]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] DATETIME     NULL,
    [TypeID]      INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblType] (
    [TypeId] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Type]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TypeId] ASC)
);
```

View for GridView display

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwPeople]
    AS SELECT p.Id,
        p.FirstName,
        p.Surname,
        p.DateOfBirth,
        t.[Type]
    FROM [tblPerson] AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblType] AS t ON p.TypeID = t.TypeId
```

Default.aspx bit

```
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="60%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="edit" CommandName="Edit" CssClass-="button" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="update" CommandName="Update" CssClass-="buttonupdate" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CssClass-="buttoncancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' Width="150px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>' Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>' Width="150px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateOfBirth" SortExpression="DateOfBirth" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfBirth" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth", "{0:d}") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateOfBirth" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth", "{0:d}") %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Default.aspx.cs bit

```
namespace GridViewTestApp1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        //Connection String from web.config File  
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GridViewTestDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ShowData();
            }
        }

        //ShowData method for Displaying Data in Gridview  
        protected void ShowData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ID, FirstName, Surname, DateOfBirth, Type from vwPeople", con))
                {
                    adapt.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }

        }

        protected DataTable GetData(string sSQL)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, con))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            return dt;
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            // NewEditIndex used to determine index of row being edited
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            ShowData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            CDBFunctions DBFunctions = new CDBFunctions();

            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            //Finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update
            // ID can be retrieved from the cell, as it is a bound field
            // Ediable fields are all template fields so need to use FindControl to retrive them
            string sID = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox txtFirstName = gvr.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtSurname = gvr.FindControl("txtSurname") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtDateOfBirth = gvr.FindControl("txtDateOfBirth") as TextBox;
            DropDownList ddlType = gvr.FindControl("ddlType") as DropDownList;

            string sDateOfBirth = txtDateOfBirth.Text;
            DateTime dtDateOfBirth;

            DateTime.TryParse(sDateOfBirth, out dtDateOfBirth);

            // Get DropDownList value
            string sTypeID = ddlType.SelectedValue;
            int iTypeID;
            int.TryParse(sTypeID, out iTypeID);

            string sSQL = string.Format("UPDATE tblPerson set FirstName = '{0}', Surname = '{1}', DateOfBirth = '{2}', TypeID = {3} WHERE ID = {4}", txtFirstName.Text, txtSurname.Text, DBFunctions.ConvertDateUSFormat(dtDateOfBirth), iTypeID, Convert.ToInt32(sID));

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();

                //updating the record  
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            //Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
            ShowData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            ShowData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // After the data has been bound we need to populate the Type drop down box
            // and selet the item that matches that row.
            // Unfortunately we cannot just databind the item in the drop down box or it would be a lot easier
            if (GridView1.EditIndex != -1)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)
                    {
                        //Find the DropDownList in the Row.
                        DropDownList ddlType = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlType") as DropDownList);
                        ddlType.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT TypeID, Type FROM tblType");
                        ddlType.DataTextField = "Type";
                        ddlType.DataValueField = "TypeID";
                        ddlType.DataBind();

                        //Add Default Item in the DropDownList.
                        ddlType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));

                        //Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList.
                        string sType = (e.Row.FindControl("lblType") as Label).Text;
                        //ddlType.Items.FindByValue(sType).Selected = true;
                        ddlType.Items.FindByText(sType).Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

CSS bit

```
.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.buttonupdate {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    color: green;
}

.buttoncancel {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    color: red;
}
```

Convert DateTime to US format string function

```
public string ConvertDateTimeUSFormat(DateTime dte)
{
    string sNewDateString = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        sNewDateString = dte.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + dte.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + dte.Year.ToString() + " " + dte.Hour.ToString("00") + ":" + dte.Minute.ToString("00") + ":" + dte.Second.ToString("00");
    }
    catch
    {
        sNewDateString = "1900-01-01";
    }

    return sNewDateString;
}
```

Hope this helps.